# Powershell adds leading space when saving text from WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, powershell

PowerShell adds a leading space (to each line from second line onwards) each time text from a WPF textbox saved to the text file. The following code demonstrate this behavior. Start with a text file that has few lines, hit save, close, reopen to see this behavior.

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

changes to

```
Test1
  Test2
  Test3
```

Is there any way to avoid this leading space whenever the text from textbox saved to text file?

```
[xml]$xaml=@"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Userinput" Height="140" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Padding="4" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        <Button x:Name="Save" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" IsDefault="True" Height="22" Margin="170,150,0,0" />        
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
#Turn XAML into PowerShell objects
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'x:Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

#Load text from text file.
$Userinput.Text = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\userinput.txt" -Delimiter "`r`n"  

#Save text
$save.Add_Click({$Userinput.Text | Out-File -NoNewline "C:\temp\userinput.txt"})

#Display Form
$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`$Userinput.Text` expects a *single string***, even if that string comprises multiple lines. Therefore, **use `Get-Content -Raw`** (PSv3+) to read the content of the file as as single string:

```
$Userinput.Text = Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath C:\temp\userinput.txt
```

---

As for **what you tried**: `Get-Content` without `-Raw` returns an *array* of strings, with each string representing a single input line by default, where any of the following newline styles are recognized as line separators, in any combination: `` "`r`n" `` (CRLF), `` "`n" `` (LF), `` "`r" `` (CR).

When PowerShell coerces an array to a string, it concatenates the string representation of its individual elements with a single space between the elements, which explains the extra spaces you saw.

The reason you saw *line breaks too* is a quirk in how `-Delimiter` works in Windows PowerShell (a problem that has since been fixed in PowerShell *Core*): the specified delimiter (separator) is *included* in each element, so that `` -Delimiter "`r`n" `` isn't just unnecessary for returning an array of lines (due to `Get-Content`'s default behavior), it actually includes the `` "`r`n" `` at the end of each line returned.