# How to get input from textboxes made in Visual Studio as values of PowerShell variables?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, powershell

I would like to offer users a graphical interface in which only a few text fields need to be filled in, in order to subsequently redirect these entries as variables into a separate file, which can be retrieved by various scripts. These scripts currently work with single prompts, but since I want to automate various processes, I want them to be prompted once when the programme starts. I have never worked with GUIs before, so I built a simple graphical interface with Visual Studio using drag and drop, which I want to integrate into my Powershell script. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to use the inputs of the text boxes as variables in Powershell. I also have a couple of checkboxes that are supposed to trigger if statements when selected, as well as a button that eventually creates the variable file and starts other scripts. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Parameter für automatische Installation" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    <Label Content="Hostname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,34,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Domain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,67,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Domain-Admin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,101,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Passwort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,135,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <Label Content="IP-Adresse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,170,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Subnetz" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,0,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="Passwort für lokalen Admin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="323,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Passwort für Backup-Admin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Margin="0,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Passwort für Notfall-Admin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="323,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="Gateway" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,239,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <Label Content="DCHP-Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,274,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,278,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <Label Content="DNS-Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,308,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,312,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="NAS-IP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,135,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="484,139,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Opacity="0.8" SelectionOpacity="1"/>
    <CheckBox Content="7zip" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="343,247,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Chrome" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="343,269,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" IsChecked="True"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Firefox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="343,290,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Notepad++" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="343,313,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="True"/>
    <Label Content="Zu installierende Software" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="332,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240"/>
    <Button Content="Rollout starten" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="604,396,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FFBB3C3C" 
    Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#FF680000"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="674,24,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/logo-regio-it.png"/>

    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52030681/45375) shows an example of WPF use from PowerShell (there are many more). I suggest you adapt it to your needs and, if you get stuck, ask a _specific_ question here.

Comment: See also: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).